# SetParent() returns ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

Tags: windows, winapi

I am seeing `SetParent( child, newparent )` returning `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` and leaving `child` parented to an old parent which I am about to destroy.

I find myself unable to find obvious differences between cases where it fails and cases where it works (similar hierarchy, albeit deeper in the failing case; same window styles for parent and child in case that works as case that does not, etc).

I have confirmed that, when `SetParent()` fails:

- `IsWindow(child)` and `IsWindow(newparent)` return true
- `newparent` is not a child of `child`
- `child` was previously a child window of a parent with the same window style as `newparent`, so top level / owner / WS_POPUP considerations are irrelevant

What else should I be checking? - what other problems might casue `SetParent()` to return `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`?

EDIT: found it. The kernel [won't let you make hierarchies nested more than 50 levels deep](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031218-00/?p=41453).

Comment: Are the old and new parent belonging to the same or to different threads? And if everything else fails, you could resort to booting Windows in debug mode and using a second computer to do kernel debugging on the first, with WinDbg or such. You could then step through your call to `SetParent` and into kernel mode and trace what the kernel-mode function `win32k!NtUserSetParent` does and at which check it fails.

Comment: What is the formatted error you get from calling GetLastError immediately after SetParent?

Comment: That's worth posting as an answer.  Though I'm thinking if your windows are nested anywhere near that deeply you're doing something wrong. :-)

Comment: @Harry: if you call winId() on any Qt widget, it creates a native window for itself and, by default, also all its siblings and ancestors. This causes the app to go from simple to explody in one easy innocuous-looking step :) Then, when you move things around in the hierarchy and it attempts to recursively reparent children, SetParent() fails as in my question leading to widgets holding on to stale HWNDs and subsequent abyssal horrors. The underlying issue isn't Qt specific, of course, Qt just makes deeply nested hierarchies easy to accidentally create.